# Select columns based on exact row value matches

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to select columns of a specified integer value (24). However, my new dataframe includes all values = and > 24. I have tried converting from integer to both float and string, and it gives the same results. Writing "24" and 24 gives same result. The dataframe is loaded from a .csv file.

```
data_PM1_query24 = data_PM1.query('hours == "24"' and 'averages_590_nm_minus_blank > 0.3')
data_PM1_sorted24 = data_PM1_query24.sort_values(by=['hours', 'averages_590_nm_minus_blank'])
data_PM1_sorted24
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum working example? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: share sample input data and expected output. And your dataframe structure

Answer (score 0):

Please try out the below codes. I'm assuming that the data type of "hours" and "averages_590_nm_minus_blank" is float. If not float, convert them to float.

```
data_PM1_query24 = data_PM1.query('hours == 24 & averages_590_nm_minus_blank > 0.3')
```

or you can also use,

```
data_PM1_query24 = data_PM1[(data_PM1.hours == 24) & (data.averages_590_nm_minus_blank > 0.3)]
```

Hope this solves your query!

Comment: THANK YOU for quick response, the first solution works :) so I stick to that. It works with and as well.